# Visual Studio 2015 build solution does not work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Sorry I am kinda new to C#/.NET and Visual Studio.

The project was built by my supervisor, and I am suppose to make some changes on it. I tried to make some changes on the `ModuleController` file, but when I click `Build Solution`, it runs, but it did not affect the website. The controller contain SQL function, even if I make any changes on this file (including delete the entire code), and then refresh the webpage, it can still run the SQL function which has been deleted and output the result.

And when I try to `Rebuild Solution` or `Rebuild Website`, I get "circular file references are not allowed". I add `batch="false"` to `Web.config` file, it can run, but still get the first problem: the code could not reflect on the webpage.

I have read http://www.gitshah.com/2011/04/how-to-fix-circular-file-references-are.html, but I have checked my folder, there is no ascx files. Only one Global.asax file...

Why is that, is there any possible solutions?

Could anyone helps me? Thanks.

Comment: Will the solution build without your changes/updates included?

Comment: @STLDeveloper yes, the solution can build, but the changes/updates could not reflect on the website afterwards